# Is it possible to generate Apply from Tree and a MethodSymbol?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-2.10, scala-macros

I have acquired a MethodSymbol from some class, and now I want create a code that invokes that method on some tree:

```
tpe.declarations.collect {
  case acc: MethodSymbol =>
    Apply(Select(tree.duplicate, ???), Nil)
}
```

Is it possible to get the name of a method in a clean way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The universe has a `Select` factory method that takes a symbol as its second argument, so you'd just write the following:

```
tpe.declarations.collect {
  case acc: MethodSymbol => Select(tree.duplicate, acc)
}
```

Note that you don't need the `Apply` here.

Comment: Eh, I need to read the API more - I miss such obvious things.